# ActiveRecord object for billing and shipping addresses

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I have an `Order` object that `belongs_to` a BillingAddress and a ShippingAddress. I want to present my user with only ShippingAddress fields and a checked checkbox indicating that the billing address matches the shipping address. If the user unchecks the box, the BillingAddress fields appear.

This design proved painful to implement, and my `Order` object has a lot of callbacks I would rather not have.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :bill_to_shipping_address

  belongs_to :billing_address,  class_name: 'Address'
  belongs_to :shipping_address, class_name: 'Address'

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :billing_address, :shipping_address

  after_initialize  :set_billing_to_shipping_address
  before_validation :set_billing_address
  after_validation  :clear_billing_address_errors

  # Init the object with option checked
  def set_billing_to_shipping_address
    self.bill_to_shipping_address ||= '1'
  end

  # Copy shipping address attrs to billing address
  def set_billing_address
    self.billing_address = self.shipping_address if bill_to_shipping_address?
  end

  def bill_to_shipping_address?
    bill_to_shipping_address == '1'
  end

  # If shipping address matches billing, we copy the attrs, and thus duplicate errors too.
  # We only need to show the user one set of errors if addresses are the same, so remove them for billing address.
  def clear_billing_address_errors
    if bill_to_shipping_address?
      self.errors.messages.each { |k,v| self.errors.messages.delete(k) if k.to_s.split('.')[0] == 'billing_address' }
    end
  end
end
```

This feels smelly, and I have four methods along with three registered callbacks  to satisfy this need. I have no logic in the controller and the form is relatively simple.

```
= form_for @order do |f|
    # ...
    = f.label :bill_to_shipping_address, class: 'checkbox' do
      #{f.check_box :bill_to_shipping_address} Use my shipping address as my billing address.
```

This doesn't feel right. I'm also hacking around the error messages.

Questions:

1. How can I improve my design?
2. Would switching the relationships help?

   `Order has_one :billing_address` and `has_one :shipping_address` instead of `belongs_to`. Nested forms will feel more natural; in that, a parent creates children, not the other way around.

I'm reading a fair bit of refactoring books, but I can never map their examples to my own object design. I'm not that experienced I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution still relying on callbacks

validations in rails accept a "condition" option:

```
validates :shipping_address, presence: true, unless: :ship_to_billing_address?
```

for simplicity and consistency, i would advise to use a "real" attribute instead of a virtual one for `ship_to_billing_address` (attributes accessor generated from boolean columns integrate nicely with checkboxes, and rails automatically generates a `ship_to_billing_address?` method).

In order to ease access to the shipping address, you could either override the `shipping_address` method :

```
def shipping_address
  ship_to_billing_address? ? billing_address : super
end
```

...or create another method, if you fear overrides. Problem is, this approach could induce confusion (modifying in place a shipping address that is in fact a billing address without knowing it, for instance)

### Solution without callbacks

Have an eye on [DCI architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data,_context_and_interaction). Some [gems](https://github.com/ltello/dci-ruby) implement it. Using [multiple form objects with different validation rules](http://pivotallabs.com/form-backing-objects-for-fun-and-profit/) is another option.